# Azure Data Explorer Multi Database Limitations

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have an Azure data explorer cluster that receives three different categories of data. Two of these categories can be ingested using a streaming ingestion policy from the event hubs, the third data type needs to be ingested using a batch ingestion policy. Due to the complexity of the manipulation that is applied to the data when it is ingested.

I see there are limitations in terms of the queries that are possible when performing cross-cluster queries. I should not be in that position.

Has anyone come across any limitations in terms of performance/functionality availability when working with multiple databases in the same cluster?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no negative perf impact for doing cross database queries on the same cluster. the separation of databases is purely logical.